# What does the symbol 油 on Jiraiya's headband mean?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language

Jiraiya is shown wearing a headband with 油【あぶら】 drawn onto it. I know that 油 is the symbol for *abura*, and that it means "oil".

But how is it related to him? Does it have anything to do with the fact that he is a sage from Mount Myoboku?

Comment: A toad in Kaguya Otsutsuki's story has a jewlery with that symbol written on it in Naruto Shippuden episode 461.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The kanji for Oil 油 【あぶら】(*Abura*) is the symbol of Myobokuzan. Jiraiya wearing it on his forehead protector represents his affiliation to it. The symbol probably comes from their special sacred oil, which allows people to feel natural energy more easily, and evaporates outside Myobokuzan's atmosphere.

Comment: Although I have noticed nobody else, other than the Great Toad Sage, sport that kanji. Maybe I did not observe closely.

Comment: In Japan, 蛤蟆の油（gama no abura）is a type of medicine effective in treating burns, cuts, and bruises.

Comment: @Krazer Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.